# How to see VRAM of google tpu?

Tags: memory, tpu, vram

Is it possible to see the VRAM of google TPU being used?

In case of using gpu, we can identify how much memory is being used using
`nvidia-smi` or `gpustat`, but I don't know how to identity it in tpu.

I need help :)

Thank you, in advance.